# Optimal LDA210 optocoupler circuit for mains detection

Tags: resistors, mains, opto-isolator, ohms-law

I am trying to sense mains with an ESP32. For that I plan to use this circuit:

[image]

I want to optimize the resistors from *If current* in order to lower the power (W) they use so they don't get hot.

According to the datasheet ([page 43](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf)), the ESP32 has *45kΩ* pull up resistors, so I was planning to use external *10kΩ* to give it some margin.

I was trying to calculate what is the minimum *If current* I can use in order to use as little power as possible, to reduce waste and the resistors temperature since I will place this in a small PCB. Following [this article](http://electronicsbeliever.com/how-to-determine-optocoupler-operation-saturation-or-linear/), I searched for a high *CTR* bidirectional optocoupler ([LDA210 datasheet](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/6C6B20D3E493C49985256A2C00697D43/$file/Lda210.pdf)) and tried to calculate the minimum *If current* needed:

Optocoupler datasheet params:
[image]
[image]

Minimum *If current* for *typical CTR* calculation 
[image]

My concerns:
This looks too tiny current to me, but I cannot find in the optocoupler ([LDA210) datasheet](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/6C6B20D3E493C49985256A2C00697D43/$file/Lda210.pdf) any *minimum forward current*. Am I missing something?
Is the *Input Control Current* the minimum Input current or affecting the equations in any way?

Comment: In your previous question you had 4 Mohm at the 230 V AC side and I then mentioned that that would result in an extremely low current. I also made some suggestions on how to reduce the power dissipation. So explain why you are now suggesting even higher value resistors. My guess is that the current will be so low that the optocoupler will not work.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, exactly, your comment made me wonder what would the optimal resistor be, and when I started calculating I got these values that look ridiculously low. The article uses 300k but it does not say where that value comes from. So I decided to post a question to find out where my calculations are wrong, or what concept I am missing. I tried with 1M ohms in total and it seems to work, but It might be just pure luck. Thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Comment: *The article uses 300k but it does not say where that value comes from.* 230 V / 300 kohm = 0.76 mA which is a usable current for an opto coupler or a sensitive LED. Also 230 V * 0.76 mA = 170 mW which is low enough for a single 0.25 W resistor.

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I don't know :) Is that **0.76** something that everybody knows empirically, or is it written anywhere? I will change my design accordingly!

Comment: *Is that 0.76 something that everybody knows empirically, or is it written anywhere?* It is not that complex and it doesn't need to be 0.76 mA. You could use 1 mA with a 220 k ohm resistor, that would also work but at the cost of slightly higher power dissipation. Probably it is more like: someone used 300 k and that worked. That schematic was put on the internet for all to see. Many saw it and also used 300 k as that was proven to work.

Comment: Your design calculation based on the imprecise mains voltage and imprecise optocoupler parameter values is not practical and not reliable at all.  If you are making just one prototype, you can  use a wall wart or phone charger to get 5V DC first. and then start your design. Of course you can also a dismantle one of those cheapy 200VAC 5W LED lamps to extract some tiny transformer or cap dropper to step down to 3V or 5V DC.

Comment: Example of cheapy 200V AC LED lamp with tiny AC to DC PSUs: Capacitive Power Supply - Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider using a capacitor dropper in series with a resistor that limits excessive surge currents. That capacitor value is chosen so that it has the correct impedance to supply sufficient current at the lowest AC line voltage (with a little margin to spare). Assume that the series resistor is somewhere in the region of 3300 Ω.

I would also use a simulator to double check everything.

From the opto data sheet I'd be considering a nominal mid range input current of about 2 mA RMS as appropriate. From a subsequent comment: -

> *How did you get to "2mA RMS"? I can't find anything in the datasheet
> that gives me a hint on what to use.*

Look at the graphs such as this one: -

[image].

The lowest led drive current is 0.5 mA and, that figure tallies with the maximum current transfer ratio graph (red mark ups by me): -

[image]

So, at your minimum supply voltage you should be aiming for between 0.5 mA and 1 mA. I added the RMS bit on the end to make it more convenient for any AC numbers you were considering. So, at maybe mid range voltages, 2 mA is about right. What you don't want to do is run on the rising slope of the CTR graph cause you'll get odd results at different voltages.

Comment: Thanks @Andy! How did you get to "2mA RMS"? I can't find anything in the datasheet that gives me a hint on what to use. I will also look into the *capacitor dropper*

Comment: Look at the graphs. Pretty much the lowest led drive current is 0.5 mA and that roughly tallies to the maximum current transfer ratio graph (maybe 1 mA for that graph). So, at your minimum supply voltage you should be aiming for between 0.5 mA and 1 mA. I added the RMS bit on the end to make it more convenient for any AC numbers you were considering. So, at maybe mid range voltages, 2 mA is about right. What you don't want to do is run on the rising slope of the CTR graph cause you'll get odd results at different voltages.

Answer (score 4):

The LDA210 has Darlington outputs (your schematic symbol does not show this), so very small LED currents will indeed work.
But if you design your circuit to trigger at 4 µA, it will be very sensitive to noise.

Please note that the typical CTR is not guaranteed; you have to use the minimum value of 300 %.

Also note that the CTR is guaranteed only for a forward current of 1 mA, and will go down for very small currents:

[image: LDA210 CTR vs. If]

The maximum sensitivity is near 0.5 mA. Below about 0.1 mA, the CTR cannot be estimated from the graph, and the minimum might be well below 100 %, so you should avoid that.